# Remove legend entries for some factors levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to remove legend elements corresponding to certain factor levels?

In my example, I wish to remove legend entries for the grey factor levels (1-5), and only keep the levels "Best", "Suggested", and "Worst".

I have tried a number of hacks already, but most of them have either removed the grey coloring of the bars (in groups of 25 each) or only left me with the bars that I colored red, yellow, and green.

```
# ggplot2
barplot <- ggplot(training_results.barplot, mapping=aes(x=name, fill=factor(a))) # filling based on a column ##mapping=aes(x=name, fill=factor(a))
barplot <- barplot + geom_histogram(stat = "identity", aes(name,wer)) ##colour="black"
barplot <- barplot + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#555555", "#777777", "#555555", "#777777", "#555555", color.best, color.suggested, color.worst), labels=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"Best","Suggested","Worst")) # 6th = best; 7th = suggested; 8th = worst
barplot <- barplot + everyNthLabel(training_results$name,5) # only show every 5th label on x-axis
barplot <- barplot + theme_minimal()
barplot <- barplot + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5),legend.position=c(.5, .9)) # rotate labels on x-axis ##, legend.position="none"
barplot <- barplot + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(35, 45))
# Legend
barplot <- barplot + guides(fill = guide_legend(title="Models", title.position="top", direction="horizontal"))
# Axis labels
barplot <- barplot + xlab("Number of EM-Training Iterations") + opts(axis.title.x = theme_text(vjust=-0.3))
barplot <- barplot + ylab("Word Error Rate (WER)") + opts(axis.title.y = theme_text(vjust=0.2))
```

[image: The result so far; the NA values should be omitted from the legend.]

The data I'm using looks as follows, with `a` being the factor that the filling color should depend on; `a` = 6, 7, and 8 mark the highlighted cases (green, yellow, and red, respectively).

```
    a b c  name  corr   acc    H   D    S   I    N   wer
1   1 1 1 1+1+1 66.63 59.15 4167 238 1849 468 6254 40.85
2   1 1 2 1+1+2 66.66 59.29 4169 235 1850 461 6254 40.71
3   1 1 3 1+1+3 66.81 59.42 4178 226 1850 462 6254 40.58
4   8 1 4 1+1+4 66.57 59.08 4163 223 1868 468 6254 40.92
5   1 1 5 1+1+5 66.89 59.34 4183 226 1845 472 6254 40.66
6   1 2 1 1+2+1 66.63 59.10 4167 240 1847 471 6254 40.90
7   1 2 2 1+2+2 66.82 59.45 4179 228 1847 461 6254 40.55
8   1 2 3 1+2+3 66.74 59.31 4174 225 1855 465 6254 40.69
9   1 2 4 1+2+4 67.00 59.50 4190 226 1838 469 6254 40.50
10  1 2 5 1+2+5 66.90 59.19 4184 230 1840 482 6254 40.81
11  1 3 1 1+3+1 66.68 59.16 4170 227 1857 470 6254 40.84
12  1 3 2 1+3+2 66.76 59.23 4175 226 1853 471 6254 40.77
etc.
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First, as your variable used for the `fill` is numeric then convert it to factor (for example with different name a2) and set labels for factor levels as you need (each level needs different label so for the first five numbers I used the same numbers).

```
training_results.barplot$a2 <- factor(training_results.barplot$a,
                                      labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Best", "Suggested", "Worst"))
```

Now use this new variable for the `fill =`. This will make labels in legend as you need. With argument `breaks=` in the `scale_fill_manual()` you cat set levels that you need to show in legend but remove the argument `labels =`. Both argument can be used only if they are the same lengths.

```
ggplot(training_results.barplot, mapping = aes(x = name, y = wer, fill = a2))  + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Best", "Suggested", "Worst"),
                    values = c("#555555", "#777777", "#555555", "#777777", 
                            "#555555", "green", "orange", "red"))
```

[image]

Here is a data used for this answer:

```
training_results.barplot<-structure(list(a = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), b = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L
), c = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L), name = structure(1:12, .Label = c("1+1+1", 
"1+1+2", "1+1+3", "1+1+4", "1+1+5", "1+2+1", "1+2+2", "1+2+3", 
"1+2+4", "1+2+5", "1+3+1", "1+3+2"), class = "factor"), corr = c(66.63, 
66.66, 66.81, 66.57, 66.89, 66.63, 66.82, 66.74, 67, 66.9, 66.68, 
66.76), acc = c(59.15, 59.29, 59.42, 59.08, 59.34, 59.1, 59.45, 
59.31, 59.5, 59.19, 59.16, 59.23), H = c(4167L, 4169L, 4178L, 
4163L, 4183L, 4167L, 4179L, 4174L, 4190L, 4184L, 4170L, 4175L
), D = c(238L, 235L, 226L, 223L, 226L, 240L, 228L, 225L, 226L, 
230L, 227L, 226L), S = c(1849L, 1850L, 1850L, 1868L, 1845L, 1847L, 
1847L, 1855L, 1838L, 1840L, 1857L, 1853L), I = c(468L, 461L, 
462L, 468L, 472L, 471L, 461L, 465L, 469L, 482L, 470L, 471L), 
    N = c(6254L, 6254L, 6254L, 6254L, 6254L, 6254L, 6254L, 6254L, 
    6254L, 6254L, 6254L, 6254L), wer = c(40.85, 40.71, 40.58, 
    40.92, 40.66, 40.9, 40.55, 40.69, 40.5, 40.81, 40.84, 40.77
    )), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "name", "corr", "acc", "H", 
"D", "S", "I", "N", "wer"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, Didzis. Using your patch makes the plot render, but the legend disappears entirely. Could it be that ggplot2 cannot find a mapping between the `values` and `breaks` defined above?

Comment: I can't answer to your question because you haven't made your problem reproducible (no data provided). I tested similar situation with iris data and that worked.

Comment: I provided the beginning of my dataset above. Would you possibly be able to share your simulation? I reckon the difficult part is to change the color every 25 bars (dark to light grey) AND, at the same time, highlight a number of distinct bars.

Comment: Updated my answer with solution that should work now.

Comment: The detour via the auxiliary variable `a2` definitely did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know this worked for individual barplots, but when I tried this for a stacked barplot, it keeps giving me error that I've only specified few breaks but there are many others.Any idea on how to remove the legends items for such cases ?

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: When I try this it keeps all my bars the same color and the legend disappears. Any pointers on where to find an alternative answer to this? Thnks! **UPDATE -> restarted R and now works!!**

Comment: This still worked for me in terms of hiding the groups that I wanted hidden from the legend, but I can no longer choose the color the hidden category (it defaults to grey)