# Remove legends for each point and keep only those which are outliers for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made the plot below

[image]

I want to know how I can remove the legend for the points at the top and keep only those legends for points around 0?

My code is as followed:

```
ggplot(AVE, aes(x=Date, y=GCContent)) + geom_point(aes(colour=Run),size=3)
```

Comment: For future questions it would be good if you could have a wee read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove selected labels (factors) from legend in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801950/remove-selected-labels-factors-from-legend-in-ggplot2)