# ggplot legend show a subset of colors for ordered factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with many years each with its own line I make it an ordered factor as I want different colours and series for each year. The problem I have is the legend becomes huge. Because they are ordered I was hoping just to show colours at the decade values to reduce the legend, but keep the color scheme.

```
library(ggplot2)
years = 50:100
n = 60
n_years = length(years)

data = data.frame(year = rep(years, n), x = rnorm(n = n * n_years), y = rnorm(n = n * n_years))
data$year = factor(data$year, ordered = T)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = year, col = year)) +
  geom_line()
```

Can my plot keep the colors but only have a legend for 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100?

Following the comment below I tried to apply an answer but to no avail, see below for my attempt.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
years = 50:100
n = 60
n_years = length(years)
cols = viridis(n_years) ## get the default color scheme
breaks = seq(from = 50, to = 100, by = 10)
col_for_decade = cols[years %in% breaks]

data = data.frame(year = rep(years, n), x = rnorm(n = n * n_years), y = rnorm(n = n * n_years))
data$year = factor(data$year, ordered = T)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = year, col = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = breaks,
                     values =col_for_decade)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801950/remove-legend-entries-for-some-factors-levels 

I think this is what you're trying to do?

Comment: @mlcyo When I try, will update my question to show my attempt. I get the following error `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 51 needed but only 6 provided.` I wonder if there is subtlety between an unordered and orderded factor. I would appreciate it if you could apply the links answer to my context.

Comment: Instead of `scale_color_manual()` use `scale_color_ordinal(breaks = breaks)`.

Comment: If you write the answer as that I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer thanks to 27 phi in the comments

```
library(ggplot2)
years = 50:100
n = 60
n_years = length(years)
breaks = seq(from = 50, to = 100, by = 10)

data = data.frame(year = rep(years, n), x = rnorm(n = n * n_years), y = rnorm(n = n * n_years))
data$year = factor(data$year, ordered = T)
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, group = year, col = year)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_ordinal(breaks = breaks)
```

Comment: `group_by = year` should be `group = year`. The edit is less than 6 characters so I can't do it myself...