# Remove some legend entries in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove some legend entries in my `ggplot`.

Previously, this was possible by defining the `breaks` parameter in the relevant `scale`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801950/remove-legend-entries-for-some-factors-levels?noredirect=1&lq=1). However, that functionality seems to be broken with a recent update.

Example:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  
  geom_col(aes(x = 1:nrow(mtcars), y = disp, fill = paste(cyl))) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey50", "grey60", "grey70"),
                    breaks = c("4"))
```

[image: Incorrect plot]

While this code snippet only diplays one legend item, as intended, it does not allow to control the colours of the non-displayed elements.

With the `breaks` attribute omitted:

[image: Correct plot, but wrong legend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a named `values` argument:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = 1:nrow(mtcars), y = disp, fill = paste(cyl))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("4" = "red", "6" = "green", "8" = "blue"),
                    breaks = c("4"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How could I implement this if I use a predefined scale such as `scale_fill_viridis_d`?

Comment: @mzuba Simply don't specify the `values` argument in `scale_fill_viridis_d`.